# How to use Histogram or table DataFrame as a predictor in linear regression?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a model that can calculate the concentration of dark matter particles in a halo, There are already packages and methods to spawn particles in a radial grid according to a specific density profile called NFW profile. I take each realization of particles and turn it into a histogram, I want to use this histogram as my predictor, each histogram in the predictor set corresponds to a response called the concentration parameter c. This should be an easy task since I did one similar before, but here I encounter a problem, every histogram in the set is divided into 100 bins, but the bin size isn't the same for each histogram, for example I have this histogram that corresponds to c=5:

```
    Bin Edges  Histogram Values
0    0.000486                21
1    0.002544                39
2    0.004602                73
3    0.006660                60
4    0.008718                64
..        ...               ...
95   0.195999                83
96   0.198057                64
97   0.200115                63
98   0.202173                74
99   0.204231                70
```

And this histogram corresponds to c=20:

```
    Bin Edges  Histogram Values
0    0.000085                76
1    0.002147               188
2    0.004209               205
3    0.006271               216
4    0.008333               230
..        ...               ...
95   0.195968                40
96   0.198030                36
97   0.200092                45
98   0.202154                40
99   0.204215                42
```

I turned the histogram to a table for clarity, as you can see the bin_edges differ between different predictors so I cant reduce this 2 dimensional data to a single dimension.

My attempt was this:

```
import numpy as np
from halotools import empirical_models
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error, mean_absolute_error, r2_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd


# Define the range for concentration parameter (c) and radius (r)
min_c = 4.0
max_c = 40.0
M = 1E15  # Mpcs
z = 0.0  # Redshift
num_samples = 300  # Number of samples
num_bins = 100  # Number of bins in each histogram


# Generate random concentration values (c) within the specified range
concentration_values = np.random.uniform(min_c, max_c, num_samples)

# Initialize lists to store features (X) and target values (y)
X = []
y = []

# Generate NFW density profiles and extract relevant information
for c in concentration_values:
    # Generate a realization of particles
    nfw_profile = empirical_models.NFWProfile()
    nfw_radial_positions = nfw_profile.mc_generate_nfw_radial_positions(halo_mass=M, conc=c)
    # Make a histrogram from the realization that is divided into 100 bins
    nfw_hist, bin_edges = np.histogram(nfw_radial_positions, num_bins)
    # Create a DataFrame from the histogram values and bin edges
    hist_table = pd.DataFrame({'Bin Edges': bin_edges[:-1], 'Histogram Values': nfw_hist})
    X.append(hist_table)
    y.append(c)


# Split the dataset into training, validation, and test sets
X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
model = LinearRegression()
# Train the model on the training data
model.fit(X_train, y_train)

# Predict concentration parameters on the validation set
y_val_pred = model.predict(X_val)

# Evaluate the model's performance on the validation set
mse = mean_squared_error(y_val, y_val_pred)
mae = mean_absolute_error(y_val, y_val_pred)
r2 = r2_score(y_val, y_val_pred)

# Print the evaluation metrics
print("Mean Squared Error (MSE):", mse)
print("Mean Absolute Error (MAE):", mae)
print("R-squared (R^2) Score:", r2)
```

But I kept getting this error:

```
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. LinearRegression expected <= 2.
```

Any ideas?

Edit: here's the full error

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\contextlib.py", line 135, in __exit__
    self.gen.throw(type, value, traceback)
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\PycharmProjects\NFW_profile\lib\site-packages\sklearn\_config.py", line 353, in config_context
    yield
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\PycharmProjects\NFW_profile\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 1152, in wrapper
    return fit_method(estimator, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\PycharmProjects\NFW_profile\lib\site-packages\sklearn\linear_model\_base.py", line 678, in fit
    X, y = self._validate_data(
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\PycharmProjects\NFW_profile\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py", line 622, in _validate_data
    X, y = check_X_y(X, y, **check_params)
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\PycharmProjects\NFW_profile\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 1146, in check_X_y
    X = check_array(
  File "C:\Users\Raeed\PycharmProjects\NFW_profile\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py", line 951, in check_array
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Found array with dim 3. LinearRegression expected <= 2.
```

Comment: Where exactly? Please update the question to include the full error trace (and remove any code that may come *after* the error) - see how to create a [mre].

Comment: @desertnaut I updated the error

Comment: `X` needs to be 2D, that is, its dimensions should be `number of samples x number of features`. In your case the error is indicating that `X` is not 2D. You need to find a way of representing `X` in a 2D format of `samples x features`.

Comment: @some3128 Exactly what I did, I simply divided the histogram value at each bin by the bin size to get a simple array and got a decent result, wonder if there is another way to get a better result though? anyways thanks!

Comment: What does `print(X_train.shape)` return? Checking if it matches the expected dimensions.

Comment: If I recall correctly, each element in X_train had (100,2) shape so X_train should be (100,2,300)

Comment: The shape of `X_train` needs to be strictly 2D. In your case it's 3D. If I understood correctly, `(100, 2, 300)` means `300` histograms, where each histogram has `100` bins for which you record `2` things (the bin edge and the bin count). Would you be able to make the bin widths the same across all histograms? I think that would help get rid of a dimension whilst preserving meaningful information for linear regression. `X_train` would thus become `300 samples x 100 bin counts`. Each sample (row) records the bins count across 100 bin edges, where the bin edges are the same across all samples.